Implement a method to send reminders from a Telegram Bot on a Channel/Group and Private Chat
My Telegram bot acts as a calendar for my favorite team's matches. It should scrape from a site that publishes the match calendar, put this calendar in a local SQLite database and access it via commands on Telegram (/prossime, /prossime10, /calendario). I also want that if it finds a match on today's date to send a message on a Telegram channel. I managed to get reminder to work as a command, but I have no idea how to make it work for automatic execution.

I can't send messages with send_match_reminder() either privately, on the channel, or in a group.

I can get the three basic commands to respond to me even on groups, however I would like to be able to implement this possibility on channels too (if it were possible).

In the event that it is not possible to call commands on the channel, I would at least like the reminder function to run every morning and if it finds a match it sends a post to the channel with the match information.


import asyncio
import requests
import telegram
import os
import string
import locale
import random
import logging
import schedule
import time
import sqlite3
from lxml import html
from datetime import datetime
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext, CallbackQueryHandler

load_dotenv()

CONNESSIONE_DB = sqlite3.connect('JUVENTUS_MATCHES.db')
CONNESSIONE = CONNESSIONE_DB.cursor()

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'it_IT.UTF-8')

async def start_bot(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    await update.message.reply_text("HI!")

              .
              .
              .
              .
              .

async def get_next_match():
    global CONNESSIONE_DB, CONNESSIONE
    CONNESSIONE.execute("SELECT * FROM MATCHES ORDER BY DATA")
    MATCHES = CONNESSIONE.fetchall()
    TODAY = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    for MATCH in MATCHES:
        if MATCH[2] >= TODAY:
            return MATCH

    return None

async def get_next_10_matches():
    global CONNESSIONE_DB, CONNESSIONE
    CONNESSIONE.execute("SELECT * FROM MATCHES ORDER BY DATA")
    MATCHES = CONNESSIONE.fetchall()
    TODAY = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    NEXT_10_MATCHES = []
    for MATCH in MATCHES:
        if MATCH[2] >= TODAY:
            NEXT_10_MATCHES.append(MATCH)
            if len(NEXT_10_MATCHES) == 10:
                break

    return NEXT_10_MATCHES

async def get_all_match():
    global CONNESSIONE_DB, CONNESSIONE
    CONNESSIONE.execute("SELECT * FROM MATCHES ORDER BY DATA")
    MATCHES = CONNESSIONE.fetchall()
    TODAY = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    ALL_MATCHES = []
    for MATCH in MATCHES:
        ALL_MATCHES.append(MATCH)

    return ALL_MATCHES

async def get_today_match():
    global CONNESSIONE_DB, CONNESSIONE
    TODAY = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    CONNESSIONE.execute("SELECT * FROM MATCHES WHERE DATA =?", (TODAY,))
    MATCHES = CONNESSIONE.fetchall()  

    for MATCH in MATCHES:
        if MATCH[2] == TODAY:
            return MATCH

    return None 

              .
              .
              .
              .
              .

async def send_reminder(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    MATCH = await get_today_match()
    if MATCH:
        MESSAGE = f"⚠️ <b>OGGI GIOCHIAMO!</b> ⚠️\n\n"

        if MATCH[0] == "Serie A":
            MESSAGE += f" <b>{MATCH[0]} - {MATCH[4]}\n⚽️ {MATCH[1]}\n {string.capwords(datetime.strptime(MATCH[2], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))}\n {MATCH[3]}</b>\n\n"

        else:
            MESSAGE += f" <b>{MATCH[0]}\n⚽️ {MATCH[1]}\n {string.capwords(datetime.strptime(MATCH[2], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))}\n {MATCH[3]}</b>\n\n"

        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=MESSAGE, parse_mode="HTML")

    else:
        MESSAGE = f"<b>❗️NON CI SONO PARTITE IN PROGRAMMA❗️</b>"
        await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=MESSAGE, parse_mode="HTML")

              .
              .
              .
              .
              .



def main():
    app = ApplicationBuilder() \
        .read_timeout(100) \
        .write_timeout(100) \
        .token(os.environ["BOT_TOKEN"]) \
        .build()

    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start_bot))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("prossima", next_match_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("prossime10", next_10_matches_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("calendario", get_all_command))
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("reminder", send_reminder))

    app.run_polling()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The Bot works via commands, but I would like to make it automated so that it can send reminder messages to the channel/group/private chat as well as respond to the three types of fundamental commands that I would like to implement.

You could use a cron job. You can create them locally on your own computer (Here's a tutorial for Linux and MacOS), but this requires your computer to be on and ready to execute the job.
For Windows, you could use the Windows Task Scheduler (Windows tutorial).
This way, you can set a time for the script to run and check if there is a match on the current day, and if it matches then it can send you a reminder.
In order for your bot to respond to commands, you would need a way to have it running constantly, waiting for you to ping it, which you would need to pay for with something like AWS, or run locally on a computer/server.
Alternatively, you can use services like cron-job.org to run the script online.

Hi, thanks for the reply!  I have already evaluated the use of Cronjob, however I consider it not suitable in my case, as the Bot must remain in service 24 hours a day and is hosted on a VPS.  Therefore, I wanted to adopt a more practical solution.
